# ZFS: Trying to remove top-level drive from Zpool

Tags: linux, freebsd, zfs

I have a zpool called storage that contains a five device raidz1 array.

Today I went and bought another 3TB device and put it in my enclosure. However, instead of creating a new pool and adding that device to it, I made a mistake and added it to my existing storage pool.

Now I have a top-level device that I want to remove called `sdg` (that's the new drive). Every time I try to remove it I get:

```
cannot remove sdg: only inactive hot spares, cache, top-level, or log devices can be removed.
```

So how do I remove this device now? If this device fails, my entire pool will be unavailable. I'm thinking I should go buy another drive and at least it will be mirrored, but I just can't believe there isn't a proper way to do this.

This is my status dump:

```
pool: storage
state: ONLINE
scan: scrub canceled on Wed Jul 23 17:26:08 2014

config:

 NAME                                 STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
 storage                              ONLINE       0     0     0
   raidz1-0                           ONLINE       0     0     0
     ata-ST3000DM001-1CH166_Z1F1PYM6  ONLINE       0     0     0
     ata-ST3000DM001-1CH166_W1F24CSC  ONLINE       0     0     0
     ata-ST3000DM001-1CH166_W1F2372R  ONLINE       0     0     0
     ata-ST3000DM001-1CH166_W1F24BTK  ONLINE       0     0     0
     ata-ST3000DM001-1CH166_Z1F2KKLW  ONLINE       0     0     0
   sdg                                ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

Comment: My understanding is that `sdg` is now part of the striped storage pool. Because the pool is striped rather than mirrored, it is impossible to remove `sdg` from the pool. The only way to get it back is to copy your data from the `storage` pool to another device, destroy the pool and recreate it without sdg. Then create a new pool for sdg to do whatever you wanted to use it for.

Comment: Everything I read in the zfs documentation said that a stripe could not grow like that. In fact, people have come up with some rather interesting things to do so that you can increase the same array.

Comment: If I can't remove it, can I add a couple more drives and make another stripe out of sdg and the two new drives?

Comment: Once you added the drive to the pool, you can't remove it.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I don't think that you are able to add a couple more drives and make another stripe out of sdg and the two new drives. I believe that the sdg would have had to be specified as a striped volume with the two extra disks when added to the pool. There is no `zfs convert` functionality.

Comment: @chronic I wonder what documentation you read. Increasing zpool size is just a matter of adding a disk or even a new stripe/mirror/raidz to it. The only trick in some cases is that you need to perform a zpool set autoexpand=on after adding the disks. Same goes to extend space on a single device zpool, resize underlying this, autoexpand=on and then off and new space is available.

Comment: sorry. let me be clear. The comment above said that when i put in sdg, it became part of the original stripe which is why I can't remove it. The docs are clear saying that you can't increase an existing stripe. you can add more stripes or mirrors to increase the overall pool but you cannot increase an existing array within the pool

Comment: so this top-level device is not the biggest vulnerability in my pool. if it goes, the pool is toast. the docs say I can add another drive and mirror it but I won't be able to stripe it. Is this true or does someone know a way to get sdg and a couple of new drives into a stripe?

Comment: Follow up: I added another drive and mirrored it. Couldn't figure out a way to stripe it. So now I have a raidz1 and a mirror. It's not what I want but at least it's redundant. It'd be nice if they could figure out a way of handling top-level, non-redundant detachments better

Comment: [Some info about removal](https://www.delphix.com/blog/delphix-engineering/openzfs-device-removal)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, removing a vdev (which this drive is) from a pool is not supported by ZFS currently (but there is [work ongoing](http://blog.delphix.com/alex/2015/01/15/openzfs-device-removal/) to support it). The work around would be to dump your data out of the pool and recreate it, then put the data back.

Answer (score 0):

***Follow-up:*** for those who are reading this since then, this is possible at least from FreeBSD 12.2-RELEASE (however, man page for `zpool` doesn't mention this in the `remove` section in 12.2, however `zpool remove` allows the removal on non-redundant top vdevs too, **if the pool has enough freespace**).

Comment: This was interesting, so to test I made a 4-device RAIDZ1 vdev, then concatenated a non-redundant 5th vdev. Trying to remove the non-redundant vdev failed: `cannot remove md4: invalid config; all top-level vdevs must have the same sector size and not be raidz.` I destroyed that, and created a new tank: a 2-drive mirror, concatenated with another 2-drive mirror, concatenated with a non-redundant fifth device.  **That** allowed me to remove the fifth device, then work backward to detach/remove the second mirror, etc.  It appears any top-level RAIDZ is a deal-breaker. FreeBSD 13.0.

Comment: This has been my experience. I was rolling mirrors this whole time and was surprised my new RAID-Z2 vdevs couldn't be removed.